# The code in the manual that is actually seemed to be wrong

Tags: haxe

I was learning Haxe. And I found that a code that is in the official manual doesn't be compiled in https://try.haxe.org/. and I wonder why and how to fix the code?

the code is the one in here: https://haxe.org/manual/types-enum-using.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try.haxe.org assumes that the class that contains the entry point `main()` is called `Test`, while the code example you linked uses `Main`.

It appears to work fine once you change `class Main` to `class Test` in the code snippet: https://try.haxe.org/#68274

---

Note that some other code examples from the manual may not compile because try.haxe.org still runs Haxe 3.4.4, while the current release is 4.0.5. To work around this, people usually use this fork of try.haxe that lets you specify the Haxe version to use in the options tab:

http://try-haxe.mrcdk.com/

[image]

Comment: Hey, the link was thankful, but unfortunately, about the name of the class having the main function, I changed it 'Main' to 'Test' and also the "Module Name" blank was "Test" in  the website, but with that version(well also other versions seems to have errors with this code anyway) throwed an error to me. Can you help? The situation is here: http://try-haxe.mrcdk.com/#c7466

Comment: Hm, I guess try-haxe.mrcdk is down right now... (happens sometimes). Anyway, the official try.haxe snippet I linked seems to work fine?

Comment: Hm, I found that other normal codes also cause this problem. There should be some reasons outta the code, right? Why is it Build Failure?

Comment: Hold on, I will do some things that might be helping this situation.

Comment: As I mentioned, try-haxe.mrcdk seems to be down, so any build will fail for no reason. :)

Comment: Okay, then I should just wait.

Comment: Or use the official try.haxe.org.